# iPhone 4 vs iPhone 5 TestFlight issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, testflight

Distributed a build through TestFlight. The ad-hoc build works fine on iPhone 5,but will open and then crash on iPhone 4 and 4s. If compiled and run through Xcode (directly to Phone with dev provisioning profile) the build runs on both iPhone 5, 4s and 4.

Has anyone ran into this?

Comment: Get the logs from the phones.

Comment: from log: failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 22.910 (user 22.910, system 0.000), 57% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 17.455, 43% CPU

Comment: If your app doesn't finish starting up (I believe this is essentially return from the `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method) in a certain amount of time, it's killed by the system. Either you have an infinite loop or you are trying to do way too much in that method. It's possible that you have a bug that only affects new (clean) installs, try deleting the app and trying again on your phone/simulator.

Comment: not infinite and works ok on iPhone 5, caching a bunch of images

Comment: Caching a bunch of images could certainly explain it. That would take a while and go slower on the older phones. Put that code into a separate thread (`dispatch_async`).

Comment: OK Cool, this has to be it. Is there a way to override that timeout?

Comment: You can't override it directly, but as I said, do it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do debugging testflight errors (or any other, for that matter) is to get the error log, and read and understand the error message. In this case the error is:

```
failed to launch in time
```

If your app doesn't finish starting up (I believe this is essentially return from the `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method) in a certain amount of time, it's killed by the system. Either you have an infinite loop or you are trying to do way too much in that method.  In this case, the app caches images in that method, which evidently is fast enough to finish in time on the iPhone 5 but not earlier ones. The solution is to queue a `dispatch_async` call (see [Dispatch Queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)) that caches the images in the background, and return quickly from the app launch method.

Comment: Your answer is dead on, but in my specific app, it's tough because I'm needing to cache a dozen images that are required to be available immediately. I'm thinking a HUD to block so the app has a chance to launch fully.

Comment: Throw up a loading screen and use [a semaphore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) to wait for it to finish.

Comment: One more thing. Can you think of why it would directly build and work on iPhone 4 but not via TestFLight?

Comment: I believe when launching from XCode the timeout is lengthened, in order to account for the debugger.  I don't think it's dropped altogether, but it's possible.